# More user with admin rights to work on the ubuntu server

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, root

I have an ubuntu server. On this server runs an apache2 with php and MySQL. I am the admin of this server but I have a person, who is the admin of the apache2-server. I know, that you can't create a second root account, but this second admin needs rights to create new vhosts or activate apache mods. How could I do this, that this second admin can work on apache without root rights?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the sudoers file, You can allow them to sudo run certain commands as certain users.

ie. taken from the linked help

`dgb     boulder = (operator) /bin/ls, (root) /bin/kill, /usr/bin/lprm`

Then user dgb is now allowed to run /bin/ls as operator, but /bin/kill and /usr/bin/lprm as root.

You will need to find the applications that he will need to be able to run. ie. /etc/init.d/apache2

`dgb boulder = (root) /etc/init.d/apache2` plus other commands that they might need to run

[Suders Help](http://linux.die.net/man/5/sudoers)

Also you will probably need to add them to a group that has write access to the sites-enabled site-avaliable folders so that they can edit the config files.

Answer (score 0):

Add your second admin to the "admin" group:

```
sudo usermod -a -G admin userName
```

Also make sure that the `/etc/sudoers` file has the following line:

```
%admin  ALL=(ALL)   ALL
```

This allows people in group "admin" to run any and all commands by prepending them with "sudo" as this:

```
sudo edit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
sudo service apache restart
```

Comment: Note that `admin` group is deprecated in favour of group `sudo` for this purpose..it is only kept for backward compatibility..

Comment: Which password will have this user type in when he want to run this comands? His normal password or my sudo password?